# Can someone confirm this set does not form a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm asked to determine whether this set forms a group: 
$G_4 = \{q\in \mathbb{Q} :q \ne 1 \}$ with the operation * defined by $a*b = a+b-ab$

I belive it's not a group as 1 can't be the identity because $q\ne1$ I also can't think of another number which could be the identity. Would that be the correct way of proving the set $Q_4$ is not a group?

Comment: Use `\mathbb{Q}`, it will render as $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: $0$ is a neutral element for your operation.

Comment: "I can't think of something that would fit" is a good bit short of being a rigorous proof.

Comment: I suggest doing some explicit calculations. Can you find a number $b$ so that $b\*2=2$? What about $b\*5=5$? This will help determine if there is an identity element.

Comment: More constructively: it's a group. Follow Gregory Simon's advice to try and find the identity element, then use that to show how to find $a^{-1}$ for any $a$.

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly associative:  $(a*b)*c = [(a + b - ab) + c] - (a+b - ab)c = a + b - ab + c - ac - bc + abc = \\ a + b + c -ab -bc -ac + abc$.

So the only option left is that there doesn't always exist an inverse.  $a*b = a + b - ab = 0 = a + (1-a)b$.  Solve for $b$: $b = \dfrac{a}{a - 1}$.  Thus the only element without an inverse would be $1$, but you've defined $1 \notin G$.

Thus, you have an abelian group!

Comment: Do I not need to check for closure and the identity?

Comment: @Henrymcp yes.  Those should be easier

Answer (score 4):

Remark that, for $a, b \in G$,

$$(1-a)(1-b) = 1- a*b$$

and that the map $x \mapsto 1-x$ is a bijection $\mathbb Q^\times \to G$.

So this equation says precisely that if we transport the group structure of $\mathbb Q^\times$ along this bijection, we obtain the operation $*$ that you describe. Hence $*$ is a group law on $G$ with neutral element $0 = 1-1$, and moreover $G$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^\times$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $a\ast b=1-(1-a)(1-b)$. Define the function $\varphi$ from the non=zero rationals $\mathbb{Q}^\ast$ under multiplication to $G_4$ by $\varphi(x)=1-x$.

Then $\varphi(xy)=1-xy=1-(1-\varphi(x)(1-\varphi(y))=\varphi(x)\ast\varphi(y)$. So $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism.

It not hard to verify that $\varphi(x)$ is one to one and onto. So $\varphi$ is an isomorphism. It follows that $G_4$ is a group.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$a+b-ab=1\iff a(1-b)-(1-b)=0\iff(a-1)(1-b)=0$$

and since $\;a,b\neq1\;$ we get the operation is closed, i.e. $\;a+b-ab\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{1\}\;$

You can check it is associative as well (it is simple but interesting), and also

$$a=a*e=a+e-ae\implies e(1-a)=0\iff e=0\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;a\neq 1$$

and we have neutral element.

Finally:

$$0=a*b=a+b-ab\iff (a-1)(1-b)=-1\iff b-1=\frac1{a-1}\iff b=\frac{a}{a-1}$$

which is well defined since, again, $\;a\in\Bbb Q\setminus\{1\}\;$